# Est-ce que ça se dit « J'y ai étudié le norvégien, en plus le pratiquant avec les locuteurs natifs » ?

Tags: grammaire, participe-présent

C'est pour expliquer que ça s'est passé en même temps. J'hésite sur le gérondif, est-il correct côté grammatical? Puisque c'était dans le passé… y a-t-il besoin de modifications? En gros, je suis en train de composer la lettre formelle et je voudrais être sûr que c'est correct.

Answer (score 5):

Le gérondif est correct, mais tu compliques.

> J'y ai étudié le norvégien en le pratiquant avec des (locuteurs) natifs.

Encore mieux:

> J'y ai étudié le norvégien auprès de natifs.

Grammaticalement, le gérondif français est simple. Nous l'utilisons peu car la répétition du son [ɑ̃] est peu musicale.

Answer (score 3):

Pourquoi ne pas simplement le specifier de deux facons, puisque c'est exactement ce que vous voulez dire?

...
J'ai appris le norvégien en suivant des cours et en le pratiquant avec des locuteurs natifs.

Answer (score 2):

Le problème n'est pas l'usage du gérondif en soit mais peut-être avec le choix des mots. « Étudier » implique plus que la simple pratique avec des locuteurs natifs et implique qu'on suit des cours. « Apprendre » est un terme qui permet d'éviter l'ambiguïté.

Tu peux dire :

> J'ai appris le norvégien en le pratiquant avec des locuteurs natifs.

ou si c'est le cas :

> J'ai appris le norvégien en suivant des cours avec des locuteurs natifs.

Le gérondif est tout à fait correct mais je pense que dans ce cas là il serait plus idiomatique d'employer une autre tournure si tu ne veux pas spécialement dire que tu as suivi des cours :

> J'ai appris le norvégien au contact de locuteurs natifs.

Comment: merci à tous, vous avez raison je le complique. mais je le fait parce que je dois souligner que ces deux choses se déroulaient en même temps. Au total j'ai : J'ai appris le norvégien en suivant des cours et en le pratiquant avec des locuteurs natifs. <---votre avis?

Comment: @user5169 : je pense que les deux personnes qui ont répondu ont cru que "apprendre le norvégien" = "le pratiquer avec des locuteurs natifs", et pas deux choses différentes. Votre nouvelle phrase est parfaite et plus claire pour dire ce que vous voulez dire.

Comment: Grammaire OK. Remplacez "Locuteur natif" par "natif" (meme si les 2 sont corects).